# Check the data for users

Tags: c

I got frustrated about the requirement that prohibited same student ID.

Assume i need to type 3 student ID:

- First:1234
- Second:4567
- Third:1234 (same ask the user to type student name again)

But i have no idea of how i can scan all the previous data and compare the data users type.
Thanks for help.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int Num;
    printf("Enter a number for student:"); //enter the number of student
    scanf("%d",&Num);
    int i,a,CheckId;
    int myArr[Num];

    for(i=0;i<Num;i++)
    {
         printf("\n\nEnter student ID:");//type the StudentID
         scanf("%d",&myArr[i]);
    } 

    //This part i want to check whether the data is same
    do
    {
         printf("Enter a number");
         scanf("%d",&CheckId);
         if(CheckId==myArr[i])//Assume the number is same
         {
             break;
         }
    }while(CheckId!=myArr[i]);//Assnume the number is not same and continue
    //But how can i check the previous data
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use tags to describe the programming language or technology your question is about. I've re-tagged your question as `C`; feel free to fine-tune if you're using some specific dialect.

Comment: What requirement? What are you talking about?

Comment: The same student id is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a nested `for` loop inside `do-while` loop, and then compare the entered value with all the array values inside that `for` loop.

Also, you can use `while(1)` at the end instead of the condition you have written, as that condition can never be `false` since, you `break` out of the loop if it is `false`.

**EDIT**: (On OP's Comment)

In your `do-while` you have used `while(CheckId!=myArr[i])`, I suggested you to replace it with `while(1)`, however that is not necessary.

You need to continuously (indefinitely) accept the input from the user until it is equal to one of the values in the array.

You can break out of the inner `for` loop on successful comparison, but before you `break` out, you set a `flag = 1;` which you need to monitor in the outer `do-while` loop to `break` out of it.

You can do it in two ways:
1.

```
 do {
 ... 
 if(flag == 1)
      break;
 }
 while(1);
```

2 .

```
 do {
 ...
 }
 while(flag != 1);
```

Comment: I can validate the data now.I am sorry i can't comprehend the part of while(1)

Comment: I fix the problem.But,i seemed to be get wrong.Because i need to continue typing data and checking the data (whether have already exit)in my project.Can u give me some hints to do that.Thanks

Comment: So when do you want to exit the `do-while`, I mean on what condition?

Comment: The condition is the number of students_ID. My thought is that the users continue to type the students_ID.When they type the same ID.The if condition emerge and ask them type again